# Case Statement in MDX

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I am trying to pull the top 10 names of employees whose

```
[Measures]. [count] is > 3 for priority 1, 
[Measures]. [count] is > 4 for priority 2 and
[Measures]. [count] is > 5 for priority 3.
```

I am able to write only for any one of the above. Can you please help me in writing the case statement?

Currently the code is.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MCount] AS IIF([Measures].[Count]>3,[Measures].[Count],"")

SELECT 
NON EMPTY
{
[Measures].[MCount]
}
ON COLUMNS
,
{
NONEMPTY
(
TOPCOUNT(
[Item].[Names].CHILDREN,
10, 
[Measures].[Count] 
),
 [Measures].[Count]
)
}

ON ROWS FROM [item]
WHERE [Item].[Priority].&[1];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result using the Generate and Existing functionality as below-

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MCount] AS 

CASE WHEN [Item].[Priority].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Item].[Priority].&[1] AND     Aggregate([Item].   [Priority].CURRENTMEMBER,[Measures].[Count]) > 3 THEN ""
 WHEN [Item].[Priority].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Item].[Priority].&[2] AND Aggregate([Item].                    [Priority].CURRENTMEMBER,[Measures].[Count]) > 4 THEN ""
 WHEN [Item].[Priority].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Item].[Priority].&[3] AND Aggregate([Item].            [Priority].CURRENTMEMBER,[Measures].[Count]) > 5 THEN ""
 END

SELECT 
NON EMPTY
{
[Measures].[MCount]
}
ON COLUMNS,
{
NONEMPTY
      (
        GENERATE({[Item].[Priority].&[1],[Item].[Priority].&[2],[Item].[Priority].&[3]}
        ,TOPCOUNT(EXISTING [Item].[Names].CHILDREN,10, [Measures].[Count] ),
        [Measures].[Count]
      )
}

ON ROWS FROM [item]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The value of MCount is varying for every Priority. Was wondering how the case statement of having ,different values of Mcount for different priorities as mentioned in the post be achieved. Can you please help with that part too?

Comment: Ok. It should be again simple. You can just replace With member with the below code. It should now work!! I've updated my answer in my previous post

Comment: getting this error: Aggregate functions cannot be used on calculated members in the Measures dimension.

Comment: I understand.. Your meadure MCount is a calculated measure so aggregate cannot be applied on a calculated measure. Try using the Sum function instead of Aggregate you should be able to get the result.